# Does this recurrence relation define a Gaussian process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

Assuming

$$\mu \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\sigma \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$$
$$X_0 \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu, \sigma)$$
$$X_{t+1} \sim  \operatorname{Normal}(X_t, \sigma)$$

is the stochastic process $X_0, X_1, \ldots, X_t, \ldots$ a (special case of a) Gaussian process?

---

Here is a function implementing the recurrence relation.

```py
import numpy as np

def generate(mu=0, sigma=1, iters=10**3):
    x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma) * np.ones(1)
    for _ in range(iters):
        new_x = np.random.normal(x[-1], sigma)
        x = np.append(x, new_x)
    return x
```

And here is an example of using the function to create a plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2018)

for i in range(100):
    plt.plot(generate(), alpha=0.5, color='k')

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('$X_t$')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is the discrete random walk, because any variable with a Normal$(X,\sigma)$ distribution has the same distribution as $X + Z$ where $Z$ has a Normal$(0,\sigma)$ distribution.

Comment: and the plot illustrates what whuber pointed out  because the variance increases with $t$.

Comment: Note that $X_t \sim N(\mu, (1+t)\sigma^2)$ and $\text{cov}(X_s,X_t)=(1+\min(s,t))\sigma^2$

Comment: Nice, these comments address and expand beyond my question. Thanks.